# How to see whats new in the git main repo without doing a pull

Tags: git, version-control

everyday I come into work and I do a "git pull" to get all the updated code in my develop branch.. can someone please tell me a why before I do my pull to see what changed

Answer (score 2):

You could do a `git fetch` and then `git log origin/X` to view changes or `git diff X origin/X` to see the difference between your branches. Once you are happy to merge your changes in, you can do a `git merge origin/X` while in X.

Answer (score 1):

After a `git fetch origin` you can use the command `git log --left-right --graph --cherry-pick --oneline HEAD...origin/master` which will show the difference of commit between you and `orign/master`.

Answer (score 0):

You can **fetch** the code and review the **log** in [staging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#The-Three-States):

```
➜  cortex git:(master) ✗ git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 1229, done.
...
Resolving deltas: 100% (720/720), completed with 117 local objects.
From github.com:icortex/test
   087dfaf..7212fc2  master    -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      test-jobs  -> origin/test-jobs
➜  cortex git:(master) ✗ git log origin/test-jobs
```

As you can see the branch `master` has changes and `test-jobs` is a new branch. Then you can check the log on each branch in "origin".

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading [this explanation](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/) of `git pull`, `git fetch`, `git merge` and their relations.

To cite this document:

> Why not git pull?
>
> Well, git pull is fine most of the time, and particularly if you’re using git in a CVS-like fashion then it’s probably what you want. However, if you want to use git in a more idiomatic way (creating lots of topic branches, rewriting local history whenever you feel like it, and so on) then it helps a lot to get used to doing git fetch and git merge separately.